# Display toolbar for Google Maps marker automatically

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a marker and when I open the map it shows the marker. When I click on it it shows the title and a toolbar which includes two buttons on the bottom right of the map which let me launch intents to navigate to the marker or show it in google maps. I would like to have these displayed automatically when the map is opened rather than having the user to click on the marker.

Like this :-) ...
[image]
I can't seem to work out how to do this.

I have tried:

```
// create marker
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
        new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("title");

// adding marker
googleMap.addMarker(marker).showInfoWindow();
googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
```

But this just shows the marker title and a button on the top right to go to my location not the two toolbar intent buttons on the bottom right.

Like this :-( ...
[image]
I'm a bit stuck any ideas?

Comment: Have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 18):

The overlay that appears when a marker is clicked, is created and destroyed on-the-spot implicitly. You can't manually show that (yet).

If you must have this functionality, you can create an overlay over your map with 2 `ImageViews`, and call appropriate intents when they're clicked:

```
// Directions
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
        "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=51.5, 0.125&daddr=51.5, 0.15"));
startActivity(intent);
// Default google map
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
        "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:51.5, 0.125"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Note: you need to change the coordinates based on Marker's `getPosition()` and the user's location.

Now to hide the default overlay, all you need to do is return true in the `OnMarkerClickListener`. Although you'll lose the ability to show `InfoWindows` and center camera on the marker, you can imitate that simply enough:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        marker.showInfoWindow();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(marker.getPosition()));
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Did google add another way to display them without clicking the marker? Or is this still the only option

Answer (score 11):

I added a feature request here:
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7652

Comment: It's been 5 years and nothing has happened apart from it being assigned to 5 different Googlers.

Comment: Too low priority issue, they'd probably never implement it ;)

Answer (score 9):

Quoting the doc:

> In a lite-mode map, the toolbar persists independently of the user's
>   actions. In a fully-interactive map, the toolbar slides in when the
>   user taps a marker and slides out again when the marker is no longer
>   in focus.

Seeems like there is no way to persist the toolbar in your case since its an interactive map. You might want to try using lite-mode if that is a requirement: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lite

Also looking at your code:

```
// create marker
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
        new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("title");

// adding marker
googleMap.addMarker(marker).showInfoWindow();
googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
```

The very last line: `googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);` is redundant unless you are explicitly setting it to false beforehand. The doc states:

> Sets the preference for whether the Map Toolbar should be enabled or
>   disabled. If enabled, users will see a bar with various
>   context-dependent actions, including 'open this map in the Google Maps
>   app' and 'find directions to the highlighted marker in the Google Maps
>   app'.
>
> By default, the Map Toolbar is enabled.

The link: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings.html#setMapToolbarEnabled(boolean)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

if i'm not mistaken you want to show the two buttons that related to the marker on the right botton side of the map and those buttons has some dependency to the marker if i'm true so you just need tu implement a new method like code below and just call this method on create and sure in your marker click listener

```
@Override
public void markerIntentButtonShow(Marker marker) {
      //setvisible(true) to your side buttons or call some Intent
      Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), MarkerViewDetails.class);
      i.putExtra("marker_snippet", marker.getSnippet());
      startActivity(i);
}
```

and call the method in your click listener

```
        googleMap
                .setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                            markerIntentButtonShow(marker);
                    }
                });
```

and in your onCreateView

```
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
        new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("title");
googleMap.addMarker(marker).showInfoWindow();
markerIntentButtonShow(marker);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue..... if you are okay with not letting the user browse in the map and just focus on your marker, you can use [lite-mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lite) map....
Quote from documentation

> In a [lite-mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/interactivity?hl=en#map_toolbar) map, the toolbar persists independently of the user's actions. In a fully-interactive map, the toolbar slides in when the user taps a marker and slides out again when the marker is no longer in focus.

Again from [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lite#intents_to_launch_a_map_view_or_directions_request)

> Also by default when a user taps the map, the API starts the Google Maps mobile app. You can override this by using GoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener() to set your own listener. You can also [disable](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/interactivity#disabling_click_events_in_lite_mode) click events on the map, by calling setClickable() on the view that contains the MapView or MapFragment.

Answer (score 2):

For the toolbar you have outlined in red, you can disable it using the [setMapToolbarEnabled() method in UISettings](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings#setMapToolbarEnabled(boolean))

From the documentation:

> Sets the preference for whether the Map Toolbar should be enabled or
>   disabled. If enabled, users will see a bar with various
>   context-dependent actions, including 'open this map in the Google Maps
>   app' and 'find directions to the highlighted marker in the Google Maps
>   app'.

Code example to  disable the two buttons:

```
//Disable Map Toolbar:
mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```

Just in case you were also wondering about the zoom buttons, you can disable them like this:

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Show a DialogFragment instead of the info window and handle everything in it.

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    DialogFragment markerWebView = DialogFragment();
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(marker.getPosition()));
    markerWebView.show(fm, "fragment_marker");
    return true;
}
```

OR

use the marker clicks to turn an overlay on/off using a [facsimile of a Google map button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130000/add-custom-button-to-mapfragment-with-the-same-style-of-maps-app/24131755#24131755)

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);


@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    //here turn on the overlays for nav turns etc. for this marker.
    return false
}

@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    //here turn off the overlays for nav turns etc.
    marker.hideInfoWindow();
}
```