# Android - Google Maps API - Markers as Buttons

Tags: android, google-maps

***Is there any way to program Google Map markers/location pins to be buttons?***

I would like to have the markers on the map clickable, to move onto the next Activity.

Any ideas?

Apprececiate it & thanks!

Comment: there is an onMarkerClick method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14226682/2026242

Comment: Sure, no problem.  Can you give a concrete example?  What do you want to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure this has been answered before.  [Display toolbar for Google Maps marker automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690711/display-toolbar-for-google-maps-marker-automatically/27868841#27868841)

Set an setOnMarkerClick handler.  Then in onMarkerClick do your stuff and return false.