# Android Google map version-2 show direction and Google map icon

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps

In my Android application my map screen shows direction and Google map when click marker on the map. I use the following in my application.

XML:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In code:

```
GoogleMap googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
        R.id.map)).getMap();
```

I have marked the direction and Google map icon marked in blue color. please see the image of my map screen.

[image]

How to hide direction and Google map icon from map fragment?

Comment: You have to set setMapToolbarEnabled to false refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690711/display-toolbar-for-google-maps-marker-automatically/38743138#38743138)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR version:

Try overriding [OnMarkerClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener.html) and return `true`.

Longer version:

When you return `true` you say to `GoogleMap`

> I, the developer, handled a click on the Marker. You, the GoogleMap, don't have to do anything.

So as a result `GoogleMap` does not perform its default action which in this case would be: show those buttons (which you don't want).

Comment: Thanks it is working. please explain me how the return true  of OnMarkerClickListener hide the options?

Comment: One important problem occurred by that solution. if I implement  OnMarkerClickListener with return true custom info window does not open. please check.

Comment: yeah, you have to do it by yourself

Comment: How do you open the info window if you are returning true?

Answer (score 25):

Google Map provides a simple boolean method for this:

```
gmap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```

And You are done.

Answer (score 3):

```
     @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
            // for Map tool disable
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);

           // for Zoom Button Enable on Google Map
mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

          //for Location  Button enable on Google Map
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Called [Map toolbar](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/controls#map_toolbar)

> You can enable and disable the toolbar by calling UiSettings.setMapToolbarEnabled(boolean).

Comment: This is just a very short version of an older answer and does not contribute to answering the question.