# Show directions button in Google Map when Info Window opened programmatically

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a map in my android application with several markers. When I click on any of the markers the info window appears and also a directions button on the bottom right hand side corner just like the picture below shows.

[image: Google Maps]

The problem is that I also open the info window programmatically based on user inputs within the app. I do this using marker.showInfoWindow() but this way it doesn't show the directions button. I have googled around and not found anyone with a similar issue, was hoping there was a way for the button to appear and if so how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display toolbar for Google Maps marker automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690711/display-toolbar-for-google-maps-marker-automatically)

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same issue... showInfoWindow() does not cause the Google buttons to appear. I have tried setMapToolbarEnabled(true); and it does not work.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do as follows:

```
GoogleMap myMap;
myMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
```

You can get all sample project code on my github [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/GoogleMap-InfoWindow-android) and try yourself:)
Just long click on map to set up a marker, click it, show the `infoWindow`, and finally, it will show the button.

[image]

Comment: But I still need to click the marker for the directions button to display? I want the button to appear when I show the info window programmatically, not when I show the info window because I clicked on the marker.

Comment: Is it possible to move these buttons to the left side of the screen instead of default right side?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky From [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28688624/4186942) I think the answer is no..

Comment: @bijang Actually, you can use `padding` property on the map, and that will move the buttons over.  The problem with that approach is - it will move ALL buttons on the map.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky yeah I know that padding thing. However, there is no default method for moving those button I think

Comment: @Daniel Julio, you can use the following MapFragment properties: map:mapType="normal" and map:liteMode="true. In LiteMode the toolbar shows by default without the need of clicking. You lose the possibility to zoom in and out though.

Answer (score 3):

For the button group you have , you can disable it using the setMapToolbarEnabled() method in UISettings.

Code example to disable the two buttons:

```
//Disable Map Toolbar:
mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```