# How to show Map Toolbar onMapReady

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

By default, map toolbar (right bottom corner) will show when we click map marker. I want to show map toolbar when map ready (without click marker).

Comment: Don't think you can. see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690711/display-toolbar-for-google-maps-marker-automatically