# How to activate the map toolbar when I return true in OnMarkerClickListener?

Tags: android, google-maps, events, google-maps-markers

Returning true to onMarkerClick can consume the event, but we lose the infoWindow display, map toolbar and camera positioning.

Then I know if I want to:

1. Positioning the camera use the method: `mMap.moveCamera()`
2. Show infoWindows use method: `mMarker.showInfoWindow();`
3. And if I **try** to show the map toolbar, I use: `mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);`

> But apparently using the sentence in point 3 is not enough to display the map toolbar. So what could I add in the code? Knowing that in onMarkerClick I will return true and when I return false all three functions are given by default.

```
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        mMap.animateCamera(
                CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ROOTS, 16),  //update
                2000, //durationMs
                new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        markerRoots.showInfoWindow();
                        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true); //NOT SUFFICIENT
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                    }
                }
        );
        return true;
    }
```

If there is something that was not understood, please let me know.

Regards

Comment: Question looks a bit weird to me. Have you added title and snippet values when adding the marker? All things you are trying to do is default functionality of a marker. It will automatically show map toolbar, position map and infowindow on marker click.

Comment: Already set up marker options. The theme is that I want to display the infoWindow and the map toolbar right after the animation @AtulVasudevA

Comment: I need to use animateCamera() but if I return false onMarkerClick does not take it. Then I need to manipulate this event returning true to be able to use a camera positioning other than the default. I did this, what I would need to do is show the map toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Map toolbar cannot be made visible programmatically.

This can be a workaround, manually create the map toolbar and create intents to fire up Google maps.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27829994/5783417)

Answer (score 0):

### Provisional solution

My purpose was:

- to the first click of the marker to perform an animation
- and then the animation display the infoWindow and the map toolbar automatically.

But as I could not make it done automatically, the code was me depending on the zoom and at least two clicks on the marker.

Then and before the animation the camera zoom will have a value. So I used`mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;` to get it and evaluate based on the zoom if I am able to consume the event (**return true**) or perform the default behavior(**return false**), ie display the infoWindow and the toolbar of the map.

---

Execution and interaction flow:

1. Click on the marker.
2. The animation is executed (*zoom=16.0*).
3. Click on the marker.
4. If `zoom==16.0` then I show the imageViews.
5. Then, modify the zoom by interacting with the map.
6. Item 1.

   ```
   public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

       //Activate the default behavior after the animation and when clicking
       float zoom = mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
       if (zoom == 16.0) {
           mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
           return false;
       }

       mMap.animateCamera(
               CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ROOTS, 16),  //update
               2000, //durationMs
               new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {   
                   @Override
                   public void onFinish() {
                       //Disable the toolbar after the animation                            
                       mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
                   }
                   @Override
                   public void onCancel() {
                   }
               }
       );
       return true;
   }
   ```

> The answers of the event will be depending on the zoom, be it applying the behavior by default or a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

No solution by now... when setOnMarkerClickListener return true toolbar is not visible.
Best option for me:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(marker -> {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                marker.showInfoWindow();
                //mMap.animateCamera to some point like this
               Point targetPoint = new Point(marker.x, marker.y - 350);
               LatLng targetPosition = projection.fromScreenLocation(targetPoint);
               mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(targetPosition), 100, null);
            }
        }, 100);
        // MOST IMPORTANT
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a touch down/up events, with the assumption that you have 1 marker in the center initially, like:

```
fun View.showMapsToolbarByTouchingMarkerInTheCenter() {
    val x = width / 2f
    val y = height / 2f

    val downEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, 0)
    dispatchTouchEvent(downEvent)
    downEvent.recycle()

    val upEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, x, y, 0)
    dispatchTouchEvent(upEvent)
    upEvent.recycle()
}
```

And then you can:

```
googleMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(location)...)
    .showInfoWindow()

googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, zoomLevel))

lifecycleScope.launch {
    delay(100)
    binding.map.showMapsToolbarByTouchingMarkerInTheCenter()
}
```

It's awful, but it works.